# searching and moving files using python

Tags: python, file

I have been trying to write some python code in order to get each line from a .txt file and search for a file with that name in a folder and its subfolders. After this I want to move that file in a preset destination folder.

I have tried the following code which was posted on stack overflow only but it doesn't seem to work and I am unable to figure out the problem.Any help would be highly appreciated:

```
import os
import shutil

def main():
    destination = '/Users/jorjis/Desktop/new'

    with open('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/articles.txt', 'r') as lines:
        filenames_to_copy = set(line.rstrip() for line in lines)

        for root, _, filenames in os.walk('/Users/jorjis/Desktop/folder/'):
            for filename in filenames:
                if filename in filenames_to_copy:
                    shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename), destination)
```

Comment: Trace (`print`) some of the key variables to see what is going on.  I would start with `filenames_to_copy`, `filename`, and `filenames`.  If you are not getting any error messages then it probably isn't finding the files.

Comment: Please indent the first 3 lines of code: "destination...", "with...", "filenames_to_copy"...(SO won't let me do it!! grr) The effect is that the file will be closed again after reading it's contents. Then, add `print filenames_to_copy` to see if any filenames were read and which format they are.

Comment: @user1016274: there was problem with filenames_to_copy and it only printed the last line of the file and what to do resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Without any debugging output (which you have now obtained) I can only guess a common pitfall of `os.walk`: the filenames returned in `filenames` are just that, filenames without any path. If your file contains filenames with paths they will never match. Use this instead:

```
if os.path.join(root, filename) in filenames_to_copy:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename), destination)
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is the error message? Please edit your post and display some lines of the file 'articles.txt'.